# How do i call a template class in the main function

Tags: c++, list, templates

This is the question i was given as a task however i get the error ''std::list': use of class template requires template argument list'. At the moment i am just trying to get the program to display the list when ran.

Write the definition of the function moveNthFront that takes as a parameter a positive integer  n. The function moves the nth element of the queue to the front. The order of the remaining elements remains unchanged. For example, suppose:

---

Queue = {5, 11, 34, 67, 43, 55} and n=3

---

After a call to the function moveNthFront:
Queue ={34, 5, 11, 67, 43, 55}.

---

(i)Implement the above function for a Static Queue Template class.

---

(ii)Implement the above function for a Dynamic Queue Template class

---

This is my code for for the class header:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Queue {

    T QueueList;
    T position;

public:
    // Constructs the queue class and defined the queue list and value for n
    Queue(T list, T n) {
        QueueList = list;
        position = n;

        list = { 5, 11,34,67,43, 55 };
        n = 0;
    };

    T PrintQueue();
    T MoveNthFront();
};

template <class T>
T Queue<T>::PrintQueue() {
    cout << list;
    return;
}

template <class T>
T Queue<T>::MoveNthFront() {

}
```

This is my code for the main function (i know it doesn't work, i just don't know what i need to do to make it work, it's incomplete)

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Queue.h"

int main() {

    int n;
    int Queuelist;

    Queue<int>;

}
```

Comment: What happens if you search for "list" in your code and replace everything which does not mean the std::list by a different word?

Answer (score 2):

You get the error message since

```
template <class T>
T Queue<T>::PrintQueue() {
    cout << list;
    return;
}
```

is interpreted as

```
template <class T>
T Queue<T>::PrintQueue() {
    cout << std::list;
    return;
}
```

since you use `using namespace std;` (and there is not variable named list). But `std::list` requires a template parameter, thus the error.

So two thing, don't use `using namespace std;` and always scope completely: (`std::cout` instead of `cout`), and you "list" is not a member of your class, you probably meant to pass another member to `std::cout`.

As for the templates, you do actually (almost) call it correctly. `Queue<int>;` is actually a `Queue` with `int` as template parameter! But just as for the `int`, you need to assign a variable to your initialization:

```
int main() {
    int n;
    int Queuelist;

    Queue<int> myQueue;
}
```

But this would call the *default constructor*  of myQueue, which you have not defined. You probably meant to call `Queue(T list, T n)`:

```
int main() {
    int n;
    int Queuelist;

    Queue<int> myQueue{n,Queuelist};
}
```